# creating event gives 400 bad request - Google calendar API using AUTHLIB (Python package)

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, authlib

#### This is my request to create an event (Using AuthLib from PyPi)

```
resp = google.post(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events', data={
        'start': {'dateTime': today.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+05:30"), 'timeZone': 'Asia/Kolkata'},
        'end': {'dateTime': tomorrow.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+05:30"), 'timeZone': 'Asia/Kolkata'},
        'reminders': {'useDefault': True},
    }, token=dict(session).get('token'))
```

### The response im getting

`{"error":{"code":400,"errors":[{"domain":"global","message":"Bad Request","reason":"badRequest"}],"message":"Bad Request"}}`

## Notes:

1. I have done get requests with the same library and methods and works
2. Scopes included (as mentioned in documentation)

   - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
   - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events

## Also note:

I have gone through all existing stackoverflow answers regarding this specific error request and api endpoint, and most of them have an issue with their time formatting which i have tried all off, now im sticking with the google api docs time format.

Comment: @khelwood *Regarding this specific error request and api endpoint ofc
I stand by it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [gcsa](https://github.com/kuzmoyev/google-calendar-simple-api) library ([documentation](https://google-calendar-simple-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?badge=latest)). It handles time formatting for you:

```
from gcsa.google_calendar import GoogleCalendar
from gcsa.event import Event

event = Event(
    'My event',
    start=today,
    end=tomorrow,
    timezone='Asia/Kolkata'
)
calendar.add_event(event)
```

Install it with

```
pip install gcsa
```

Comment: This is great! But the authlib is a universal OAuth handling library so I would love to stick to this library